# How to input 4 Numbers in just one line with different Int in java?

Tags: java

The problem is so simple. I want to, just like Python, find a method, that helps me to input 4 numbers with different Int just in One line. 
I mean in java, I want to,
The input is: 1911
The out put is:
Year:19
Month:11

Comment: *"input 4 numbers"* The input `1911` is **1** *number* with **4** *digits*. --- As such, use `nextInt` to get the *number*, then use `x / 100` to get the number consisting of anything but the last 2 digits, and `x % 100` to get the number consisting of the last two digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
try {
    Scanner io = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = io.next();
    // Note StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
    int year = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, 2));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2, 4));
    System.out.println("year: " +  year + "month: " +  month);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Test

```
1911
```

Output

```
year = 19, month = 11
```

Or

```
Scanner io = new Scanner(System.in);
String year = io.next(), month = io.next();
System.out.println("year: " +  year + "month: " +  month);
```

Test

```
19 11
```

Output

```
year = 19, month = 11
```